# In iOS how to open the device browser from inside a sub view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, browser

I have a UIViewController with a sub view of a UITableViewController and static cells. On selection of a cell from the UITableViewController I would like to open the device browser with a given URL. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://stackoverflow.com/"]];
```

And no matter where from this function will be called.